# Open a file descriptor globally in C

Tags: c

If I want to declare a file in C globally then where should I close the file?

Or if I want to write data in the file from multiple functions then I have to open the file again and again in every function?

Comment: When opening a file you are getting a file descriptor (fd) which is the unique identifier of your program to the file, you can pass this fd (which is of type int if I remember correctly) as an additional parameter to your functions instead of using a global variable (Which nearly never should be done!).

Comment: You are free to open file on startup of your app and close it on close. But there i a risk to lose data if your app will crash. So, better soluteion will be to create funtcion that will open/write/close your file for every write operation.

Answer (score 1):

1) basically in the same code block where it was opened

2) no. open and close once

**0) avoid global variables**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
FILE *global;
void foo(void) { fprintf(global, "foo\n"); }
void bar(void) { fprintf(global, "bar\n"); }
int main(void) {
    global = fopen("test", "a");
    if (!global) { perror("test"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
    fprintf(global, "main\n");
    foo(); bar(); foo();
    fprintf(global, "main\n");
    fclose(global);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> If I want to declare a file in C globally then where should I close the file?

Generally speaking, you *shouldn't* declare a file or much of anything else globally.

> Or if I want to write data in the file from multiple functions then I have to open the file again and again in every function?

No, generally speaking, your multiple functions should accept a parameter that tells them what file to work with.  Of course, there has to be one that opens it.  Either that one can also be responsible for closing the file (after calling other functions between and maybe passing the file to some of them), or it can return the file to its caller, along with the responsibility for closing it.

I think you will find that if you structure things this way then the proper place to close the file will fall out naturally from the structure of the program.